# How to use service provider in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Create a shopping cart for an online store. Now I have:

My service provider:

```
<?php

namespace Alexxosipov\Cart;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;


class CartServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    public function boot() {

    }

    public function register() {
        $this->app->singleton('cart', function() {
            return new \Alexxosipov\Cart\Cart;
        });
    }
}
```

Main cart class:

```
<?php

namespace Alexxosipov\Cart;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;
use App\Cart as CartModel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
class Cart
{
   public function __construct(Request $request) 
   {
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

2 questions about that:

1. How can I pass the Request variable to my `__construct` method through service provider?
2. How do I get ready (initialized) instance of the class in any application file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.
The callback in the `singleton` function takes an $app parameter from which you can make the request :

```
$this->app->singleton('cart', function($app) {
    return new \Alexxosipov\Cart\Cart($app['request']);
});
```

2.
To do this, I would call the singleton with the name of your class :

```
$this->app->singleton(\Alexxosipov\Cart\Cart::class, function($app) {
    return new \Alexxosipov\Cart\Cart($app['request']);
});
```

And then you can typehint it and get it. For example, in a controller you might have :

```
public function show(\Alexxosipov\Cart\Cart $cart) {

}
```

Note :
You should not use another service in the register method.
Maybe you could do it like this :

In register you just bind it without the request.
In boot you populate the cart with the request.

Answer (score 1):

To explain this case, we need understand more about the Laravel Service Container. The service container is a powerful Laravel tool for managing classe dependencies and performing dependency injection.

To this case, to the closure passed in your register method, an arguments is passed too. He receives a instance of Illuminate\Foundation\Application. With this instance, you can call any available instance in service container.

Then, the solution for you is pass app argument to your closure, get a instance of request and pass it to your class:

```
 public function register() {
    $this->app->singleton('cart', function($app) {
        $request = $app->make('Request');
        return new \Alexxosipov\Cart\Cart($request);
    });
}
```

In this way you will be able to pass the Request object to the Cart constructor, but depending on Cart's responsibility, although it works, this may represent an architecture error.